# JQuery update if at bottom of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function, which in itself works fine, however it scrolls down whenever i scroll up which is not intended.
I want it to run the function ONLY if the scrollbar of the div (overflow) is at the bottom, which makes it possible to scroll up without it scrolling back down preventing the view of older messages.

```
function opdaterPost(til, fra){
        $('#beskeder_vis').load('calls/opdater_post.php?til=' + til + '&fra=' + fra);
        $("#beskeder_vis").animate({ scrollTop: $("#beskeder_vis").prop("scrollHeight") }, 1500);   
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the chat box
http://jsfiddle.net/w989Y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if the div is scrolled to the bottom by:

```
if ($("divID").get(0).scrollHeight - $("divID").scrollTop() == $("divID")outerHeight()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do it the way Facebook ticker works. When you scroll to the bottom, the `outerheight` of the container, added to the `scrollTop`, (the amount the container has been scrolled off), should give you the total content height `scrollHeight`. So do something like this:

```
$("#divId").scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).outerHeight() == this.scrollHeight)  
  {
     \\do stuff;
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not, i've added a jsfiddle showing the chat box. 
When you scroll up to watch the older messages, it scrolls back down because of the jquery function. I want it to only scroll down, if the user is already at the bottom of the div

Comment: How can you further scroll down when the user is already at the bottom? Do you mean to say that once the user has scrolled down, the content should be appended, and again automatically scroll down to the bottom? That is possible, but then it would again trigger another load, another scroll down, in an infinite loop.

Comment: Right now it scrolls down to the bottom every 2 seconds. If it detects that you're at the CURRENT bottom, it should run the function every 2 seconds. If not at the bottom, don't run the function